# Sails.js upload huge base64 image

Tags: node.js, base64, sails.js, data-uri, data-url

I have a form with input which value is data URI of image like  `"data:image/jpg;base64,/9j xxxxxxx...".`

That value is given to input when user crops image using this -> http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/
So on dragend event I fill in input value with getDataURL...

On form submit, data goes to controller where I do stuff with dataURI to get extension, base64 string etc...

Then I'm writing that base64 to a file with something like:

```
fs.writeFile(fileRoot+filePathAndName, imageBase64, 'base64', function (err) { ...
```

Everything works flawlessly. But... When I use larger images (>500kb so not that large infact) I get this error:

```
Unable to parse HTTP body- error occurred :: [Error: EUNFNTEX: Timed out waiting for known text parameters to finish streaming their bytes into the server.]
```

It's interesting that it always works on localhost :( Even with huge images.

Does anyone have an idea how can I make this work? Or even better suggest a way how this could be done using skipper or a nice service...

I'm using SailsJS v0.10.5 on node v0.10.33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried everything... Client insisted to make it client side crop and I was stuck with base64 images... So I found a hacky solution...

Inside sails app: node_modules/sails/node_modules/skipper/lib/Parser

I changed prototype.parseReq.js line 167 from:

```
var ms = 5;
```

To:

```
var ms = 100;
```

So it now it looks like:

```
function finally_waitForTextParams() {
  // Careful: No error argument allowed in this callback!

  debug('waiting for any text params');

  // Make sure the `impatient` timeout fires no more than once
  clearTimeout(timer);

  // Take a look at all currently known text params for this Upstream,
  // then wait until all of them have been read.
  var ms = 100;
  var numTries = 0;
  async.doUntil(
    function setTimer(cb) {


      // Catch-all timeout, just in case something goes awry.
      // Should never happen, but a good failsafe to prevent holding on to
      // control forever.  It this timeout was to fire, we should error out and
      // cancel things.
      numTries++;
      if (numTries > 10) {
        return cb(new Error(
          'EUNFNTEX: Timed out waiting for known text parameters to finish ' +
          'streaming their bytes into the server.'
        ));
      }

      setTimeout(cb, ms);

      // Exponential backoff
      // (multiply ms by 2 each time, up to 500)
      ms = ms < 500 ? ms * 2 : ms;

    }
```

I know this is not a good solution. If anyone has better idea, please help :)

Comment: This worked for me as well. However, I would like to understand more of what this is actually doing and maybe any CONS that this would have on the request and overall app  as i'm sure this comes with a price if the timeout is increased too much.

Answer (score 0):

it could be many things... your reverse proxy (like nginx or cloudflare) is blocking large uploads. the body parser is blocking large urlencoded/json requests.

what you should do instead is upload the image using multipart or xhr2/File API.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I really appreciate it. By saying multipart, do you mean something like this http://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty or you are just saying I should use multipart form data and upload my images the regular way?

Comment: On the back end, yes. If you use the file API, you can send the image as the entire request body. For multiparty, you can use formdata to send the image.